# Can worker roles in Azure Cloud Services have IIS as a reverse proxy?

Tags: azure, azure-networking

I have a legacy application that listens to a specific TCP port and processes the incoming requests using a homemade non-HTTP protocol. I have to deploy this application to Azure, I made some research and it seems that Worker Roles can perfectly do that ( Unlike app services, they can have an application that listens to other ports than 80 and 443). It seems that Worker roles don't include IIS by default, while Web Roles do ( and require at least one input to be an HTTP one, no problem, I can have an empty HTTP input ).

For security reasons, I don't want my application to directly face the internet, I want to have IIS facing the internet, and routing the packets back to my internal Worker/Web role so that I can configure IIS for IP filtering etc...

Is it possible to have IIS as a reverse proxy on non 80/443 ports with Worker Roles? If not, with Web Roles?

Answer (score 0):

Web/Worker roles are legacy and you really don't want to use them for anything new. If you want a reverse proxy then look at using App Gateway, or just deploying a VM and running your app on that.

Comment: The app is 15 years old, and needs to be deployed for each customer, this is why worker roles can become handy because a VM is a little bit too heavy to duplicate for each customer, but I need to be sure that the app is not directly facing internet because it's not meant for that.

Comment: Worker roles are just VMs, you can achieve something similar with VM scale sets whilst  avoiding using a service that has been deprecated.